# Javascript regex difficulties

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a string with the following:

- starts with `[A-Z]`
- contains `[a-zA-Z- '\u00E0-\u00EF]` ([Latin-1 Supplement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1_Controls_and_Latin-1_Supplement) - [Match Unicode Block Range](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block))
- any other character is forbidden
- does not end with `[- ']` or have `[- ']` next to one another.
- has at least `2` characters

**I've been trying the following:**

```
new RegExp(/^[A-Z](?!.*[- ']$).*[a-zA-Z- '\u00E0-\u00EF]$/);
```

My problem isn't that I'm not able to understand what regular expressions do, but whether they are correct.
It's very easy (or not) to write a regex that looks like it should work but misses on a few things.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit**

Valid string : `Marie-Noëlle Tranchant`, `Jean-François Copé`...

Comment: can you give an example of a valid string?

Comment: edited question - added valid string.

Comment: "does not have [- '] next to one another" all 9 possibilities here or just the three of the same character doubled up?

Comment: @jswolf19 do not have : `'space''space'` , `--` or `''`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^[A-Z](?:[- ']?[a-zA-Z\u00E0-\u00EF])+$/
```

Below is a proof of why this meets your criteria.  If you change the non-capturing group `(?:...)` to a `(...)` then it is also the shortest regexp that meets your criteria.

> starts with [A-Z]

because of the `^[A-Z]`.

> contains [a-zA-Z- '\u00E0-\u00EF] (Latin-1 Supplement - Match Unicode Block Range)
>   any other character is forbidden

because the entire thing must match character sets containing only those characters

> does not end with [- '] or have [- '] next to one another.

because `[- ']` is restricted to zero or one occurrence per following occurrence of `[a-zA-Z\u00E0-\u00EF]`

> has at least 2 characters

because the `[A-Z]` matches at least one character and the `+` after the `(?:...)` group requires another one.

Answer (score 1):

A very basic way to test regex is to take a literal string e.g. "blah this is text" and using the .match method with it.  You can open a js console (Ctrl + Shift + J in Chrome) and directly run it to see what it returns

```
"Marie-Noëlle Tranchant".match(/^[A-Z][-a-zA-Z '\u00E0-\u00EF]*[^- ']$/);
```

Comment: My problem is the few things that are missed out : `Ma5rie-No1ëlle Tra4nc6hant` and `Ma%rie-Noëlle Tranch#ant` works.

Comment: how about `/^[A-Z][-a-zA-Z '\u00E0-\u00EF]*[^- ']$/`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your regexp will do what you want. It should accept any string that starts with `[A-Z]` and ends with `[a-zA-Z\u00E0-\u00EF]` (with any characters in between, including ones you don't want to accept), although I can't say for sure since I don't know how the unescaped '-' is handled...

I think you want something more like this:

```
new RegExp(/^[A-Z](?:(?!--|''|  )[a-zA-Z\- '\u00E0-\u00EF])*[a-zA-Z\u00E0-\u00EF]$/);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit - redo**
After revisiting this thread, I noticed these comments:

"does not have [- '] next to one another" all 9 possibilities here or just the three of
 the same character doubled up? – jswolf19 2 days ago
 @jswolf19 do not have : `'space''space'` , `--` or `''`. – Stack 101 2 days ago
"

In light of this, you have to go with what @jswolf19 did.

His regex could probably be simplified a little more:

pcre:
`/^[A-Z](?:([\- '])(?!$|\1)|[a-zA-Z\x{E0}-\x{EF}])+$/`

js:
`/^[A-Z](?:([\- '])(?!$|\1)|[a-zA-Z\u00E0-\u00EF])+$/`

```
expanded JavaScript:  
^                     # start of string
   [A-Z]                     # single A-Z char
   (?:                       # non-capture group
       ([\- '])                   # capture group 1, single char from: [- ']
       (?! $ | \1 )               # not the end of string nor the
                                  #   char captured in group 1 (backreference)
     |                          # OR,
       [a-zA-Z\u00E0-\u00EF]      # a single char from: [a-zA-Z\u00E0-\u00EF]
   )+                        # end non-capture group, do 1 or more times
$                     # end of string
```

Please test answers before you mark them as correct. Others may visit this thread
in the future.